# Can not install google-chrome-stable on ubuntu 12.10 because of libnss3 (>= 3.14.3)

Tags: apt

My Vimium plugin stopped working in google chrome so I uninstalled it order to get install newer version. I can not get to install it anymore because of incorrect dependency version on libnss3 package. I tried to reinstall the package but it reinstalls to the same version.

Here is the output of the installation failure:

```
$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have 
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable 
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libnss3 (>= 3.14.3) but 3.13.1.with.ckbi.1.88-1ubuntu7 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Tried to install libnss3 to that specific version with:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3=3.14.3
```

but it does not find that version.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy libnss3`?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to purge google-chrome, libnss3, libnss3-1d, and then do an autoremove, and then an autoclean. Then install libnss3, and libnss3-1d again from official repositories.
Then go to google and redownload chrome, and reinstall.

```
sudo apt-get purge ***name of packages && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get install ***libnss3 libnss3-1d
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main` to the end of **/etc/apt/sources.list**

add gpg key

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8BAF9A6F`

Do an update

`sudo apt-get update`

Finally install libssl `sudo apt-get install libnss3`